# jquery ajax xml parsing

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, parsing

I'm trying to parse XML with jQuery, and I'm having issues doing so. I'm using this from a proven function, and it keeps skipping the ajax part. I can't for the life of me find out why I'm unable to run this.

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://my.domain.tld/php/myapi.php', // the script to call to get data          
        data: "method=get_tbl_fields", // you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php, for example "id=5&parent=6"
        dataType: 'xml', // data format      
        success: function(xml) { //on recieve of reply
            alert('it worked');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: are you getting any errors in the firebug if you have used it

Comment: What error do you get? If you put a `console.log` just before the ajax request does it get written out?

Comment: "keeps skipping the ajax part". Are you sure that your method has been called?

Comment: how does your php script look like, also the dataType should be like `dataType: 'text/xml',`

Comment: the console says `Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by changing from my local host wamp server to the actual webserver in a development platform. The API wasn't letting me query from my localhost.